# Login YouTube for using API

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a YouTube channel with linked +Page. What username / password I need to use YouTube API. If I use the primary username / password from Google Account - API returnes an error: Error = NoLinkedYouTubeAccount. Where I see it?

Comment: Which steps do you follow ? You must use OAUTH2 to access the private data of a YouTube channel. There is a PHP code example.

Comment: I use ClientLogin and cUrl.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Email=mail@gmail.com&Passwd=123456789&service=youtube&source=test');

Answer (score 0):

You should check the latest YouTube API version 3 documentation. Using ClientLogin is obsolete. It must be OAUTH 2: You use email & password to authorize YouTube privata data access, for a channel. Step 1: get & save the refreshToken. Step 2: Use the refreshToken for getting an accessToken, to be used with your YouTube API requests. (accessToken is valid for 1 hour)

Update:
That link of yours https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html 
opens a page with an error. Also, that page has a title "YouTube API Partner Dashboard".
Do need the Partner Dasboard ?

Start reading instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start
This page also has a YouTube instruction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I

BTW. This is the error message I got from that page:

```
Refused to execute script from     'https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/com.google.youtube.frontend.partner.ui.client.DeveloperApp.nocache.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html:1
```

Comment: Ok. If I will use OAuth2 I must have DeveloperKey. But on page https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html have error: "Network or server error: Could not complete the registration of the new product. Please try again later."

Comment: Thanks. Your links have been very useful.